# htaccess redirecting one url to load from another

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect one of my URLs in my website, but I get error 404 not found
I am trying to redirect this url: [http://www.stoikovstroi.com/bg/противопожарни-врати](http://www.stoikovstroi.com/bg/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8)

to be loaded from this one: http://www.stoikovstroi.com/vina/index.php/protivpojarni-vrati

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^stoikovstroi\.com\bg\противопожарни-врати$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.stoikovstroi\.com\bg\противопожарни-врати$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/vina/index.php/protivpojarni-vrati
RewriteRule (.*) /vina/$1/index.php/protivpojarni-vrati
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?stoikovstroi\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^bg/противопожарни-врати/?$ /vina/index.php/protivpojarni-vrati [L,NC,R=302,B]
```

Use this rule in `/vina/.htaccess` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /vina/

RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php/).*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I have found a way to redirect it but it seems it does't recognize the cyrilic sybols like this:
Redirect 301 /bg/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8 http://www.stoikovstroi.com/vina/index.php/protivpojarni-vrati

Comment: it redirects me to this link wich doesn't seems to be correct:
http://www.stoikovstroi.com/vina//vina/index.php/index.php/protivpojarni-vrati
it should be:
http://www.stoikovstroi.com/vina/index.php/protivpojarni-vrati

Comment: www.stoikovstroi.com redirected you too many times.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: http://www.stoikovstroi.com/vina/index.php/index.php/protivpojarni-vrati

the "index.php" in the link is writed 2 times how can I remove it so it will be written just once?

Comment: when I type this in the browser: "stoikovstroi.com/bg/противопожарни-врати"

it should redirect me to: stoikovstroi.com/vina/protivpojarni-vrati

Now is not working again....

Comment: Make sure my `302` rule is first rule in root .htaccess. It is redirecting me from `/bg/противопожарни-врати` to `/vina/index.php/protivpojarni-vrati`

Comment: I have tryed everything but still getting the same error.... "No input file specified." Maybe you can find me on skype: speedshadow93 and I will share the screen if you want to see what am I doing wrong.....

Comment: in the main folder in the ftp there is a file ".htaccess", after that in the folder "public_html" is another ".htaccess" file and inside the "public_html" fold is my folder "vina" where the current site is located. Inside the "vina" folder is another ".htaccess" file. I think the path is not correct.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already have used "rewrite" to redirect my domain name to my new web site. The old website was www.stoikovstroi.com and the new one was www.vina.stoikovstroi.com after finishing the work I redirected the domain name to www.vina.stoikovstroi.com so it load when I type www.stoikovstroi.com and here is the code in the ".htaccess" file wich is located in the public_html:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^stoikovstroi\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.stoikovstroi\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/vina/
RewriteRule (.*) /vina/$1